# How do we setup oAuth server?

Tags: php, oauth, cakephp-1.3, oauth-2.0

I want oAuth verification process for a mobile application.For that i need to setup an oAuth server which listens to the requests and grant the access tokens.How do i set this up?I didnt found any relevant help on net.Please let me know.Also it will be good if it could be done using CakePHP

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need an OAuth library for PHP that implements an OAuth service provider.

There are PECL and PEAR OAuth libraries, but my personal testimony is oauth-php as its simpler. I implemented both a server and client with it.

I cant comment on writing a service provider in Cake.

---

**Updates based on OP's comments**

Copy that directory to your PHP application to "install" it. You would need only CURL support from your host. There are no other prerequisites from the part of your host.

I did these steps to write an OAuth provider with oauth-php, do try these, google it and ask new questions when you get stuck.

1. read illustrated guides on how OAuth works
2. Studied relevant chapters from http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/ (try this order: 3,4, appendix,6 and 7 to start with)
3. read the example files included with the library, and see the how-tos in site's pages
4. hack those files and build it up your application

Comment: If this is the one you are talking about can you please elaborate the points for me..It will help.

Comment: I went through the installation instructions and it tells me to create virtualhost and reference an environment variable to it.How can i do this on my hosting server?Do i need to have a dedicated server for this?